# Как создать мобильное приложение на HTML5, но так, чтобы не отображались функции браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, android, css, app

Как создать мобильное приложение на HTML5, но так, чтобы не отображались функции браузера (просмотреть код, перевести страницу и т.п.)? И существует ли способ объединить все файлы (HTML, CSS, JS) в один apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я делал такое приложение при помощи Cordova
https://cordova.apache.org/
https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/webclient/cordova-gettingstarted_ru.html

Comment: Спасибо большое!